# SQL Server 2000/2005 query list user access

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

is there a query to list database user access and related source IPs on SQL Server 2000 and 2005? Please note that reporting service is not installed.

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this query that seems to list user access but it doesn't record source IP. Please note path has to be verified before runnning the query:

```
SELECT TargetLoginName, SessionLoginName, HostName, StartTime
FROM fn_trace_gettable('X:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\log_59.trc', default);
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

sp_who or sp_who2 should give you what you need. They won't list the ip address but they will list the hostname. sp_who2 will give you more information than sp_who.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. sp_who and sp_who2 only shows current sessions, I need also past ones, such a 'logon history'